# String dropping letters?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I am having an issue where I try to create a string but one of the letters in that string (m) is being dropped. I don't understand what is going on, how do you fix it?

This is the code:

```
typeTo.text = [typeTo.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"random" withString:@"(random (1,10000000)/10000000)"];
NSLog(@"%@", typeTo.text);
```

NSLog prints:

```
rando
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `typeTo.text` starting off as `rando` by any chance?

Comment: What is the value of `typeTo.text`?

Comment: As the log confirms, `typeTo.text` is initially equal to `rando` and not `random`. So the code you provided is correct, but the string doesn't contain any occurrence of `random`. Put `NSLog(@"%@", typeTo.text);` before `typeTo.text = [typeTo.text ...` to be sure is is not the fault of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the input string... I just tested this:

```
NSString *initialString = @"a random string is always random";
initialString = [initialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"random" withString:@"(random (1,10000000)/10000000)"];
NSLog(@"%@", initialString);
```

And it printed:

> 2012-03-17 21:15:41.276 Untitled[39581:903] a (random
>   (1,10000000)/10000000) string is always (random (1,10000000)/10000000)

It's working fine, replacing all occurrences of random with (random (1,10000000)/10000000).

Comment: Yup I found the problem, I was replacing "m" before I replace "random". Thanks